# Can't manage to use Doctrine Translatable Hint for queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I dont manage to automatically Join the translations of my entity fields.

I have a Project entity, linked to a ProjectTranslation entity.
Everything works well, but if I make a simple query :

`$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('p')
        ->from('BitProjectBundle:Project', 'p')
        ->getQuery()
        ->setHint(
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
            'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker')
        ->getResult();`

I got 75 queries, loading all the required translations :

```
74*
    SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.locale AS [...] FROM Project_translations t0 WHERE t0.object_id = ?
```

I thought the Hint was supposed to automatically left join the translations, am I missing something ?

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169763/symfony-2-3-gedmo-doctrine-extensions-translatable-caching