# Symfony 2.3 Gedmo doctrine extensions translatable caching

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I'm using [Gedmo Doctrine extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/)
All works well so far, except for translations caching.

```
$entity = $repository
            ->findByIdFullData($id)
            ->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker')
            ->useResultCache(true, $cache_time, $cache_name)
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

`findByIdFullData()` returns `\Doctrine\ORM\Query`
But the translations aren't cached. In profiler I see queries like that:

```
SELECT 
  e0_.content AS content0, 
  e0_.field AS field1 
FROM 
  ext_translations e0_ 
WHERE 
  e0_.foreign_key = ? 
  AND e0_.locale = ? 
  AND e0_.object_class = ?
```

And all the queries in profiler are to get results from `ext_translations`. How can I cache the result already with the translated strings?

Tried using Array Hydration and memCache, but ended messing up more, because my result item has uploaded media file which can't be serialized or something. Anyway I would end up rewriting most of the code.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit**:

I've tried Karol Wojciechowski's answer and it solved part of the problem. It caches when I use `getOneOrNullResult()` but not with `getResult()`. Here's some code.

In a service:

```
$query = $this->em
    ->getRepository('MainBundle:Channels')
    ->findActiveChannelsByGroupId($id);
$this->container->get('my.translations')->addTranslationWalkerToQuery($query, $this->request);

$channels = $query
    ->useResultCache(true, 900, '1__channels__active_by_group_1')
    ->getResult();
```

Channels repository:

```
public function findActiveChannelsByGroupId($group_id, $limit = null)
{
    $rs = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('c.media', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('c.group', 'g')
        ->where('c.active = 1')
        ->andWhere('g.id = :group_id')
        ->orderBy('c.sortOrder', 'asc')
        ->setParameter('group_id', $group_id)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $rs->getQuery();
}
```

If I change to `findActiveChannelsByGroupId($id, 1)` (notice limit param), it still doesn't cache, but then if I change to `getOneOrNullResult()`, query gets cached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our working code:

```
    public function addTranslationWalkerToQuery($query, $request)
{
    $config = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getConfiguration();
    if ($config->getCustomHydrationMode(TranslationWalker::HYDRATE_OBJECT_TRANSLATION) === null) {
        $config->addCustomHydrationMode(
            TranslationWalker::HYDRATE_OBJECT_TRANSLATION,
            'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Hydrator\\ORM\\ObjectHydrator'
        );
    }

    $query->setHint(
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
        'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
    );
    $query->setHint(
        \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE,
        $request->getLocale() // take locale from session or request etc.
    );
    $query->setHydrationMode(TranslationWalker::HYDRATE_OBJECT_TRANSLATION);
    $query->setHint(Query::HINT_REFRESH, true);
}
```

**EDIT:**
And if you want to "getResult"

Performing getResult changes hydration mode. Have look on AbstractQuery class method:

```
/**
     * Gets the list of results for the query.
     *
     * Alias for execute(null, $hydrationMode = HYDRATE_OBJECT).
     *
     * @param int $hydrationMode
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getResult($hydrationMode = self::HYDRATE_OBJECT)
    {
        return $this->execute(null, $hydrationMode);
    }
```

It works with `getOneOrNullResult` because it didn't changes hydration mode

```
public function getOneOrNullResult($hydrationMode = null)
```

If you want to cache translatable queries you should change hydration mode during execution getResult method to `TranslationWalker::HYDRATE_OBJECT_TRANSLATION`.

Personally I'll wrap this method into service which will handle everything associated with translations.

Comment: Do I have to add this method in every controller and call it by passing Query and Request every time I need it and only then call `getResult()`? Sorry if the question is stupid :) I'm not so good with Symfony

Comment: We have a service (contains that method) which is used to fetch entities with translations, and yes - we use it in many places in app.

Comment: So I've tried to cache some places and encountered a problem. I get result cached if I use `getOneOrNullResult()`, but using `getResult()` leaves the same problem as described in question